# ASP.NET MVC - Failed to navigate in a javascript handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Javascript, hope my question is not too obvious.

I have a button in my view: (ASP.NET MVC 4)

```
<input name="button" type="button" id="button1" value="Click me1"/>
```

I add a click Handler :

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    map = new Object();
    map['T1'] = 'Placeholder/Index';
... // Truncated 
    map['T11'] = 'Placeholder/Index';

    $('#button1').click(function ()
    {
        // alert('button1 clicked');
        window.location.href = map['T1'];
    });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

The code works fine the first time I click the button. But, the next times I get an error.
I can see in the address bar the following URL:

```
http://localhost:64321/Placeholder/Placeholder/Index
```

Why the repetition? What am I doing wrong?
(I have to use Javascript )

*(Not the real code, but simplified as much as possible to show the issue)*

Thanks in advance
**Philippe**

Comment: Remove `Placeholder/` from `Placeholder/Index`?

Comment: Then he will end up with `http://localhost:64321/Index/Index/Index/...`.

Comment: just to let you know, .click is no longer the best way to bind an event in jquery, you should use (document).on("click", "#button1", function(e) { ... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the repetition? What am I doing wrong?

Because you forgot a `/` when you declared your urls:

```
map['T1'] = '/Placeholder/Index';
...
map['T11'] = '/Placeholder/Index';
```

or to be more precise you forgot to use the Url helper to generate those urls which is obviously the only correct way to handle urls in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
map['T1'] = '@Url.Action("Index", "Placeholder")';
...
map['T11'] = '@Url.Action("Index", "Placeholder")';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck for a moment on this one.